# how to setup ssl datasource in wildfly for MSSQL and custom truststore

Tags: sql-server, ssl, wildfly-8

I need to setup datasource in wildfly to MSSQL using jtds driver and with custom truststore. The truststore is let say in \Users\user\certs.p12 file and in PKCS12 format.

I've try this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mssqlDS" pool-name="mssqlDS" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:1433/myspace;ssl=authenticate</connection-url>
    <driver>mssqlDriver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>xxx</user-name>
        <password>yyy</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

And I've try to setup path to truststore and its password also pass in the standalone.xml configuration:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="..."/>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" value="..."/>
</system-properties>
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is an error in jTDS driver http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/725/